# UITableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths not working

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm using Core Data and I have a problem. The app crashes because when I insert a new element I try to access a cell that doesn't exist but it should.

The code that matters:

```
func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        switch type {
        case .Insert:
            if let indexPath = newIndexPath {
                self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade) // This doesn't work
                print(indexPath) // Returns row 0 section 0
                print(tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0)) // Returns 0
                print(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)) // Returns nil

                let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! myCell // App crashes here because cell is nil
                configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)

                self.tableView.backgroundView = nil
            }
```

Crash Log:

```
<UITableView: 0x7ffb1b8c3000; frame = (0 64; 375 554); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7ffb1ae9a620>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ffb1ae92b40>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 10}>
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
0
nil
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Sorry for putting the log as code but there's a bug with the block quote and won't show the full log.

This is very weird because it was working fine before. I just did some changes to the code (code snippet includes changes) but didn't touch the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` and now it's not working.

Comment: what changes have you made?

Comment: The code that you see has the changes. Before that `configureCell()` was not there. But nothing else was changed in between the insertion and the cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's normal ! Indeed, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` on `UITableView` "*returns an object representing a cell of the table, or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range*". ([Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:)).

So, you can't access this cell because it do not exists yet for the `UITableView` (you are adding it !). Please, move your `configureCell` call to your datasource `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! You saved me. It does actually make perfect sense.